AWS SES emails aren't delivered (Transient bounce) with 550 Rejected by header based Anti-Spoofing policy
I tried to setup emails sending for my environment. I have my domain name (let it be <my_domain>.com) registered in AWS Route 53. I have verified domain and email address noreply@<my_domain>.com in SES Identities.
I have tried to send emails to different email addresses. Most of them are delivered successfully, but all emails to addresses on my domain @<my_domain>.com have never arived. From Virtual Deliveratility Manager I can see that diagnostice code is - smtp; 550 Rejected by header based Anti-Spoofing policy: noreply@<my_domain>.com.
I have added SPF rule for my domain record to include amazonses.com as allowed domain (because initally I have not used custom MAIL FROM), but unfortunatelly it didn't help.
Than I have tried to add custom MAIL FROM. I have added subdomain - notifications.<my_domain>.com . But recipients with @<my_domain>.com email addresses still doesn't receive email with the same diagnostic code.
Could someone please help me with this? Did I miss some configuration?

Have you set up the SPF record for the Custom MAIL FROM subdomain? Because SPF is checked on the MAIL FROM (a.k.a. Envelope From, a.k.a. Return-Path) domain and not on the Header.FROM domain.

Are you using Mimecast for your domains MX setup and have you looked at the following? https://community.mimecast.com/s/article/email-security-cloud-gateway-configuring-anti-spoofing?r=818&ui-knowledge-components-aura-actions.KnowledgeArticleVersionCreateDraftFromOnlineAction.createDraftFromOnlineArticle=1

@Reinto Yes, I have. It's setupped like this "v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all" .
But the emails to address on my domain still not arrive because of 550.
I don't use Mimecast. All my records in AWS Route 53.

So, where does your MX point to? If not Mimecast, which service? Google, Office 365, other ESP? In other words, which service is returning the 550 error?
